# Xen Vif creation xl vs xm

Tags: bridge, xen

**Hi everyone,**

I switch my server from a xend/xm Xen install to a 4.1 xl Xen install.

Therefore Xen does not create vif network interface when I launch `xl create /etc/xen/my_server.cfg` but does create vif network interface with the  command `xm create /etc/xen/my_server.cfg`

Here are sample configuration:

```
nano /etc/xen/xl.conf
vifscript="vif-bridge"

nano /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp
(network-script network-bridge)
(vif-script vif-bridge)

nano /etc/default/xen
TOOLSTACK=xl
```

**Any idea ? I'm lost :-(**

**Best Regards.**

> **[EDIT] I do not undertand but after several changes it is working now,
>   here we go:**
>
> **nano /etc/xen/xl.conf # Use the whole path not just vifscript="vif-bridge" I think the problem was there...**
>
> ```
> vifscript="/etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge"
> ```
>
> **Network on the HOST:**
>
> ```
> # The primary network interface
> auto  xenbr0
> allow-hotplug  xenbr0
> iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
> bridge_maxwait 5
> bridge_ports eth0
>
>
> # The secondary network interface
> auto  xenbr1
> allow-hotplug  xenbr1
> iface  xenbr1 inet dhcp
> bridge_maxwait 5
> bridge_ports eth1
> ```
>
> **nano  /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp # No network script sets...**
>
> ```
> (dom0-min-mem 196)
> (enable-dom0-ballooning yes)
> (total_available_memory 0)
> (dom0-cpus 0)
> (vncpasswd '')
> ```
>
> **Network VM interface with IP failover XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > IP FO  YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY > IP HOST**
>
> ```
> #The primary network interface
>
> auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static 
> address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
> netmask 255.255.255.255
>
> post-up route add YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/32 dev eth0
> post-up route add default gw YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
> ```
>
> **VIF HOST Created by XL vif8.0**
>
> ```
> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
> inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
> UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
> RX packets:1336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> TX packets:14342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
> collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
> RX bytes:81534 (79.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1268787 (1.2 MiB)
> ```
>
> **nano /etc/xen/my_server.cfg**
>
> `vif         = [ 'ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ,mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,bridge=xenbr0']`
>
> **And its' OK ! Regards !**
>
> > If you DownVote what ever the reason please give some advice and do not downvote without any explication that's not fair !!
>
> **[EDIT2] If you were using XM be Aware that with XL you have to set `vifscript="/etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge"` into `/etc/xen/xl.conf`
>   because symlink `vifscript="vif-bridge"` only works with XM !!!**

Comment: Was that meant to be an answer? If so, it belongs as an Answer below, not as part of your Question.

Comment: Thanks for driving me to this point. I add some infos because my question was missing some configurations informations. But I post an answer below after checking that my problem was due to symlinks support missing with XL...

Answer (score 1):

Be Aware that if you were using XM that with XL you have to set full path for network script, if not script isn't executed:

So for XL use you have to set :
`vifscript="/etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge"` (or another script)

into `/etc/xen/xl.conf`

because symlink `vifscript="vif-bridge"` only works with XM (on my Debian Xen install)!